# How can I return a byte array as an image from a Spring Controller, so that a browser can display it?

Tags: java, spring, http, encoding, decoding

I would like to make a GET request to a Spring Controller, and convert a stored byte array to an image, then receive the image as the response and show the image in the browser.

As test image, I'm using a 5x5 px teal solid color image exported to JPG with The GIMP: [image]

To get the base64 encoded image, I used [this webpage](http://base64.wutils.com/encoding-online/). This is the Base64 encoded string I got:

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gATQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVD/4gKwSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUA
>   AQEAAAKgbGNtcwQwAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAH5AABAAEADwAZAABhY3NwQVBQTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLWxjbXMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1kZXNjAAABIAAAAEBjcHJ0AAABYAAAADZ3dHB0AAABmAAAABRj
>   aGFkAAABrAAAACxyWFlaAAAB2AAAABRiWFlaAAAB7AAAABRnWFlaAAACAAAAABRyVFJDAAACFAAA
>   ACBnVFJDAAACFAAAACBiVFJDAAACFAAAACBjaHJtAAACNAAAACRkbW5kAAACWAAAACRkbWRkAAAC
>   fAAAACRtbHVjAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAMZW5VUwAAACQAAAAcAEcASQBNAFAAIABiAHUAaQBsAHQALQBp
>   AG4AIABzAFIARwBCbWx1YwAAAAAAAAABAAAADGVuVVMAAAAaAAAAHABQAHUAYgBsAGkAYwAgAEQA
>   bwBtAGEAaQBuAABYWVogAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLXNmMzIAAAAAAAEMQgAABd7///MlAAAHkwAA
>   /ZD///uh///9ogAAA9wAAMBuWFlaIAAAAAAAAG+gAAA49QAAA5BYWVogAAAAAAAAJJ8AAA+EAAC2
>   xFhZWiAAAAAAAABilwAAt4cAABjZcGFyYQAAAAAAAwAAAAJmZgAA8qcAAA1ZAAAT0AAACltjaHJt
>   AAAAAAADAAAAAKPXAABUfAAATM0AAJmaAAAmZwAAD1xtbHVjAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAMZW5VUwAAAAgA
>   AAAcAEcASQBNAFBtbHVjAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAMZW5VUwAAAAgAAAAcAHMAUgBHAEL/2wBDAAMCAgMC
>   AgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIU
>   FRT/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQU
>   FBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wgARCAAFAAUDAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAFAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB//E
>   ABUBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYH/9oADAMBAAIQAxAAAAFWQQT/xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   AAAA/9oACAEBAAEFAn//xAAUEQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/9oACAEDAQE/AX//xAAUEQEAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/9oACAECAQE/AX//xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/9oACAEBAAY/An//
>   xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/9oACAEBAAE/IX//2gAMAwEAAgADAAAAEL//xAAUEQEAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/9oACAEDAQE/EH//xAAUEQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/9oACAECAQE/EH//
>   xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/9oACAEBAAE/EH//2Q==

I just return this string using the Controller.

In the request, whether I use Angular or just Firefox, I set the Accept header to image/jpeg, and in Firefox, I see the following:

> the image ... cannot be displayed because it has errors

When viewing the response, I see:

[image]

[image]

Controller:

```java
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class ThumbnailController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/thumbnail/{id}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getThumbnail(@PathVariable long id) {
        return "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".getBytes();
    }
}
```

I thought that Spring would magically take care of converting the byte array to an image, but it seems I'm missing some steps. Perhaps there is missing metadata, and the browser doesn't know how to display the image, because it only has the content and doesn't know how to present it?

Comment: You're currently returning the base64 encoded value **as bytes** instead of the raw bytes... You need to **decode** the base64 encoded value and return that.

Comment: Good point ;-) Feel free to provide your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently returning the base64 encoded value as bytes instead of the raw bytes. You need to decode the base64 encoded value and return that.

For example:

```
Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
String encoded = "<base64 encoded value>";
return decoder.decode(encoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get API is return base64 encoded value as bytes Array.Basically, You have to decode base64 value returning from above API and try to render image in browser by creating file at runtime .Please check below reference code

```
public static void main(String[] agrs) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
       String msg="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";

       byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(msg.getBytes());
       File file = new File("c:\\demo2.jpeg");
       try {
           OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
           os.write(decode);
           System.out.println("Write bytes to file."); 
           os.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

hope it will help you